# assign output of function to variable in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
function to_call()
{
    echo "#1 is $1"
}

function call() 
{
    local val=$(to_call testInput)
}
```

There is no output on terminal. why?

if I change it to:

```
function to_call()
{
    echo "#1 is $1"
    return 1
}

function call() 
{
    local val=$(to_call testInput)
    echo "value is $val"
}
```

Instead of "value is 1", it is "value is #1 is testInput". What happens?

Is there any way that i could print the echo of the "to_call function" on terminal, and also use the return state?

Comment: > "Although bash has a return statement, the only thing you can specify with it is the function's status, which is a numeric value like the value specified in an exit statement" 
[source](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres no output, because of [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (which invokes a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)) and reassigns the output, ie. the function's output to stdout is reassigned to the local variable.

The bash `return` statement is to specify a status only,
like `exit` without terminating the shell. It allows to return a "exit status" (`$?`) of the function.

Variables in the scope of a subshell are not accessible to the parent process.